# Preserving PHP values in a form

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem with preserving the values written inside a textfield, if an error occurs. I have 4 textfields, and if 1 is blank it needs to show a new form, with a error message and the input in the textfield from the previous file.

I guess it's the last part of my assignment_2.php where it's wrong.

**assignment_1.php**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="sendit.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="adress" placeholder="adress"/>
         <br>
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city"/>      
         <br>
            <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="zip"/>
             <br>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

**sendit.php**

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$adress = $_GET['adress'];
$city = $_GET['city'];
$zip = $_GET['zip'];

if (!isset($_GET['name']) || $_GET['name'] == '') {
    header("Location: assignment_2.php?errmsg=1");
    exit;
}
else {
    header("Location: assignment_2.php?errmsg=1&name=$name");
}
if (!isset($_GET['adress'])|| $_GET['adress'] == '') {
    header("Location: assignment_2.php?errmsg=2&adress=$adress");
    exit;
}    
else {
    header("Location: assignment_2.php?errmsg=1&adress=$adress");
}
if (!isset($_GET['city'])|| $_GET['city'] == '') {
    header("Location: assignment_2.php?errmsg=3&city=$city");
    exit;
}  
else {
    header("Location: assignment_2.php?errmsg=1&city=$city");
}
if (!isset($_GET['zip'])|| $_GET['zip'] == '') {
    header("Location: assignment_2.php?errmsg=4&zip=$zip");
    exit;
}  
else {
    header("Location: assignment_2.php?errmsg=4&zip=$zip");
}

echo $name . "<br>" . $adress . "<br>" . $city . "<br>" . $zip

?>
```

**assigment_2.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // 1.0  Create a contactform containing name, address, city, zipcode
        //      Send it to a form handler
        //      If any of the form fields are not filled out, return to this page and 
        //      display an error containing information on how to prevent the error
        // 1.1  Preserve the input for the user
        ?>

        <?php


            if (isset($_GET['errmsg'])) {
                $err = $_GET['errmsg'];

                switch ($err) {
                    case 1:
                        $err_msg = 'Missing navn';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $err_msg = 'Missing adress';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $err_msg = 'Missing city';
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $err_msg = 'missing zip';
                        break;
                    default: 
                        $err_msg = 'I just dont like you';   
                        break;
                }
                echo '<div class="error">' . $err_msg . '</div>';

            }
        ?>
        <form action="sendit.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" <?php
                if (isset($_GET['name'])) echo 'value="' .$_GET['name'] .'"';
            ?> />
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="adress" placeholder="adress" <?php
                if (isset($_GET['adress'])) echo 'value="' .$_GET['adress'] .'"';
            ?>/>
         <br>
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city" <?php
                if (isset($_GET['city'])) echo 'value="' .$_GET['city'] .'"';
            ?>/>      
         <br>
            <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="zip" <?php
                if (isset($_GET['zip'])) echo 'value="' .$_GET['zip'] .'"';
            ?>/>
             <br>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Keep things simple!
For starters, try working on only one file, and put your errors into an array.

Then try shortening your code, and to never "copy & paste" code.

On modern sites, developpers use frameworks to validate forms, 
Keep playing with this one until it works like you want, and have a look at Symfony or Zend Framework form validation.

```
<?php

$errors = array();
if (isset($_GET['submitted'])) {
    if (!isset($_GET['name']) || $_GET['name'] == '')
        $errors[] = 'Missing navn'
    if (!isset($_GET['adress']) || $_GET['adress'] == '')
        $errors[] = 'Missing navn'
    if (!isset($_GET['city']) || $_GET['city'] == '')
        $errors[] = 'Missing navn'
    if (!isset($_GET['zip']) || $_GET['zip'] == '')
        $errors[] = 'Missing navn'
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (count($errors) !== 0)
                echo '<div class="error">' . implode("<br>", $errors) . '</div>';
        ?>

        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />

            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '' ?>" />
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="adress" placeholder="adress" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['adress']) ? $_GET['adress'] : '' ?>" />
         <br>
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['city']) ? $_GET['city'] : '' ?>" />      
         <br>
            <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="zip" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['zip']) ? $_GET['zip'] : '' ?>" />
             <br>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woah! I almost made it work. The only problem is I get an undefined index of 'submitted' What do I do with that one? give it an empty value so it doens't display? and I don't get my echo message anymore. How do I define that, now?

Comment: i corrected the code, have a look at the isset function on php documentation

Answer (score 0):

I will probably handle first client side validation, so the form will not submit until all inputs get fill, then I will do some server side validation and sanitization. BTW you don't need to have assigment2.